# Chat with separate in threads read/write actions. Write thread close instantly

Tags: java, sockets, stream, server, client

I have a task to make a chat. I have 4 classes Server, Client, Writer and Reader.
Client connect with Server. When connecting between that processes is alright. Client and Server start Reader and Write threads and Client and Server can communicate. When both of them write "exit" connecting is closed. Client process is terminated and Server is waiting for connection. Problem is when I try to connect with Server once again. Writer thread in Server **is closing** instantly.
I observed that when program is in

```
line = reader.readLine()
```

jump instantly to

```
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I really appreciate any idea :)

Here are classes:

Client

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket kSocket = null;
    ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("Client");

    try {
        kSocket = new Socket("localhost", 2222);
        System.out
                .println("Connected with: " + kSocket.getInetAddress() + " at port: " + kSocket.getPort());
        new Pisarz(group, kSocket).start();
        new Czytelnik(group, kSocket).start();
        while(group.activeCount()!=0){}
        kSocket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Uuu IOException");
    }
}

}
```

Server

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    ThreadGroup group = new ThreadGroup("Server");
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(2222);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unavaible to listen on port 2222");
    }
    try {
        while (true) {
            Socket sSocket = server.accept();
            System.out.println(
                    "Connected with: " + sSocket.getInetAddress() + " at port: " + sSocket.getPort());

            new Pisarz(group, sSocket).start();
            new Czytelnik(group, sSocket).start();
            while (group.activeCount() != 0) {
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.err.println("Socket exception :/");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("UnknownHost :/");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IO Exception :/");

    } finally {
        try {
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Writer Thread

```
public class Writer extends Thread {
Socket sOut;
ThreadGroup group;

public Pisarz(ThreadGroup group, Socket sOut) {
    super(group, "Writer");
    this.sOut = sOut;
    this.group = group;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter printer = null;
    try {
        printer = new PrintWriter(sOut.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            printer.println(line);
            printer.flush();
            if (line.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Writer is closed");

}
}
```

Reader Thread

```
public class Reader extends Thread {

Socket sInput;
ThreadGroup group;
SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");

public Czytelnik(ThreadGroup group,Socket sInput) {
    super(group, "Reader");
    this.sInput = sInput;
    this.group = group;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sInput.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(time.format(new Date()) + " " + line);
            if (line.equals("exit")) {
                System.out.println("Reader is closed");
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your "writer" is reading from `System.in`, and then closing it.  There's only one System.in, so if you close it, you won't be able to read from it again.

Comment: Okay I just delete that lines and everything works perfectly. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your "writer" is reading from `System.in`, and then closing it.  There's only one System.in, so if you close it, you won't be able to read from it again.
                    – heenenee

Okay I just delete that lines and everything works perfectly. – Kabool